# Protocol error. Cannot find protocol declaration

Tags: iphone, objective-c, protocols

We have error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'ClassWhichUseMainScene' [3]

We created file:
Protocol.h

```
#import "ScoreSystem.h"
#import "OtherSystem"
#import "OtherSystem2"

@class ScoreSystem;

@protocol SceneDelegate <NSObject>
@property (nonatomic, readonly,retain) ScoreSystem* score;
@property (nonatomic, readonly,retain) OtherSystem* system;
@property (nonatomic, readonly,retain) OtherSystem2* system2;

@end
```

And use in ScoreSystem.h

```
#import "Protocol.h"
#import "OtherSystem"
#import "OtherSystem2"

@interface ScoreSystem: NSObject <SceneDelegate> 
{
OtherSystem* system;
OtherSystem2* system2;
}
```

In ScoreSystem we want use just OtherSystem and OtherSystem2 objects. In OtherSystem use ScoreSystem and OtherSystem2, etc. 
We want create universal protocol for all system.

Answer (score 4):

You have a circular dependency between your two header files (each imports the other).  Do not import `ScoreSystem.h`  in Protocol.h, the `@class` forward declaration is enough.  The same goes for your other two imports.

As a general rule I avoid including class header files in other class header files - I just use @class everywhere and import the headers in the implementation files.

Comment: To be clear, though, you'll probably still want to import the headers in the implementation files.

Comment: @Chuck: Good catch.  I'm going to amend the answer

Answer (score 0):

Mine Problem resolved with simple import statement

```
#import "ProtocolContainingFile.h"
```